# startActivityForResult в ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

Из другой программы запускается моя активити с  GridView, при тапе по картинке запускается ActionSend. Как организовать staetActivityForResult чтобы после отправки изображения была активна активность запустившая мою?

В статус баре уведомление , тап по которому запускает активность код которой ниже

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Код MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLvImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));

    sp = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", MODE_PRIVATE);

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "ICOIN/");
    File[] filesArray = dir.listFiles();
    if (filesArray != null) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, filesArray);
        mLvImages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Код адаптера

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<File> {

LayoutInflater mInflater;
Picasso mPicasso;

public Adapter(Context context, File[] objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, objects);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mPicasso = Picasso.with(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mPicasso.load(getItem(position)).fit(). centerCrop().into(imageView);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(getItem(position)));
            getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));          
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```